# The privileges information is still missing information about suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, privileges

Currently, [privileges/edit still says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit):

> **Alternatives to Editing**
>
> If you don't have enough reputation to edit, there are alternatives:
>
> - If the post is in urgent need of editing, flag it for moderator attention.
> - If the post has a minor mistake, leave a comment for the author explaining the issue.

It's written as if suggested edits didn't exist.

Similarly, there is no privilege page for approving/rejecting edits. There's one for [approving/rejecting tag wiki edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) but that's a different privilege which is gained much later.