# Privilege descriptions out of date

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect privilege wiki for the 10k tools (Privilege descriptions out of date)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79465/incorrect-privilege-wiki-for-the-10k-tools-privilege-descriptions-out-of-date)

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools is now inaccurate.
Moderator-tools are not the highest level of privilege, `Trusted User` requires a higher level of reputation, as does protecting questions.

Comment: The title isn't descriptive, but this [earlier report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79465/incorrect-privilege-wiki-for-the-10k-tools) covers the same issue. No answer, but the comment draws the same effect that Jon's answer here does.

Comment: Those are not the only privilege descriptions that are out of date. Still no mention of suggested edits in many relevant places: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79028/the-privileges-information-is-still-missing-information-about-suggested-edits

Comment: Ok, voting to close. I added the link and a bit to the title in the other.

Answer (score 2):

The privileges pages (which are wikis) here on Meta are periodically pushed out to the other sites on the network.

This particular privilege has [already been updated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), but hasn't been pushed out yet.