# Edit a question with < 2,000 reputation?

Tags: support, edits

I was under the impression you had to have 2,000 reputation to edit a question.  Can someone explain how [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184968/size-of-serialization-in-f-vs-c/5185107#5185107) was edited by someone with only 54 rep?  It doesn't affect me personally, I'd just like to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users with less than 2k reputation [can now edit questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/), but the change will only be displayed to other users after it has been approved by users with 2k reputation or more. Unfortunately, that [isn't explained in the /privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79028/the-privileges-information-is-still-missing-information-about-suggested-edits) which is probably why you're confused.

Answer (score 3):

From the FAQ

> The other way to gain reputation is by **suggesting edits** to existing posts as a new registered user. Each edit will be peer reviewed, and if it is accepted, you will earn +2 reputation. You can only earn a maximum of +1000 total reputation through suggested edits, however.

The FAQ also states

> Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits

So you can only suggest up to 2K, beyond that you are no longer suggesting as the change goes through immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Users with less than 2000 rep can also edit, but their edits need to be approved by some other high rep users.